# How to access value in a Dictionary that has a Tuple as the Key in c#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, tuples

I have created a dictionary with Tuples as keys and a enumerator as value.

```
mKeyValue.Add(Tuple.Create(lineCount,columnID),(E)style);
```

`mKeyValue` is the dictionary.

```
static Dictionary<Tuple<int,int>,E> mKeyValue = new Dictionary<Tuple<int,int>,E>();
```

Now how to access elements in this dictionary?
I used something like this,

```
mKeyValue[Tuple<lineCount,columnID>];
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a Tuple as a Key in a Dictionary C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52220354/how-to-use-a-tuple-as-a-key-in-a-dictionary-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a `Tuple<int,int>` defined then use that as key like `mKeyValue[t];`

```
Tuple<int,int> t = Tuple.Create(1, 1);
mKeyValue.Add(Tuple.Create(1, 1), (E)21);
var data = mKeyValue[t];
```

Answer (score 2):

It's no different than usage with any other type of key. You need to pass an instance of the type, not the type (declaration) itself to the indexer.

You wouldn't say `myKeyValue[int]`, for a `Dictionary<int, ...>`, when you really wanted `myKeyValue[5]`. Just the the key looks a little more "complicated" in this case.

Example:

```
// Lookup entry for LineCount = 1, ColumnID = 4711
var value = myKeyValue[Tuple.Create(1, 4711)];
```

Basically, just like you did when adding an entry with `Dictionary<>.Add(...)`.